# Are stopping times ordered?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stopping-times

Stopping times are random variables, so they are measurable functions. Let $S$ and $T$ be stopping times. Is it always possible to say $S<T$ or $T>S$ or $S=T$?

Possible answer:
We can't compare two functions, because for some $\omega$'s $S<T$ or $T>S$ or $S=T$, right?
But S and T gets values in index set which is ordered. Sounds confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a sequence of coin flips. Let $S$ be the first head and let $T$ be the first tail.

Comment: I was confused because of $S\wedge T$, I thought that it means choosing from what is smaller S or T, but what its really means: $S\wedge T=S$ for $\omega$ where $S\leq T$ and $=T$ for $\omega$ where $T\leq S$